# como puedo hacer la siguiente tabla en firebase

Tags: php, javascript, firebase

[image: tengo la tabla de la imagen en mysql pero quiero hacerla para usarla con firebase. me gustaria saber como puedo hacer esto en el formato json que utiliza firebase]
La tabla que muestro en la imagen está en MySQL. Quiero hacer esa misma tabla pero en firebase, ¿ cómo quedaría estructurada esa tabla en forma de árbol como lo establece firebase?

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, como bien has dicho firebase tiene un formato árbol ya que se almacenan los datos en un formato JSON. Por lo tanto tendrás que desglosar los datos que tienes en la tabla en diferentes capas. Analicemos con detenimiento:

Tenemos diferentes productos, y cada producto tiene diferentes propiedades como peso, lote1, etc. Por lo que podemos hacer un padre a todos que sean los productos(todos). Dentro de éste podremos incluir los distintos productos y a su vez dentro de cada producto las propiedades de las que disponen. No te pondré la tabla entera pero como ya te imaginas quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
producto:{

 transporte1:{

   peso:4,
   lote1: etc,
   siguiente: etc
 },

 transporte2:{
  como el anterior
 }

}
```